# ChannelFactory.CreateChannel and proxy instantiation is slow in WCF

Tags: wcf

I have a client-server application, in which the client communicates with the server using WCF (WCF is used both in the client and the server).
My problem is, that instantiating the auto-generated proxy in the client, in the following way:

```
 new Service1Client()
```

takes constantly 15.xxx seconds.
I tried to solve this problem, and came to the following results:

1) Compiling and running the same code on other computers, ends up in the same way (always 15.xxx seconds).

2) Instantiating the proxy using `ChannelFactory.CreateChannel< IService1 >()`
doesn't help (it gives the same result).

My guess, is that whenever the channel factory creates a channel, it tries to do something with a 15 seconds timeout, and when it fails, it continues with creation.

By the way, I use .Net 3.5 without SP1, and cannot upgrade to SP1 :(

Thanks ahead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've seen this before, where the time was being taken in looking for a proxy server. Check your WinINET (Internet Explorer) proxy settings.

---

My specific reason for thinking "proxy server" is that it takes 15s. 15s sounds like a nice round number for a network timeout.

Comment: Thanks, I will try to check this. Although it is weird that on instantiation it looks for a proxy server - this should be performed during the first operation call or something...

Comment: I think that wasn't the problem... there was no proxy server defined on that computer.

Comment: I suggest you watch it with Fiddler or something to see if there's something going on with the network. 15s is too perfect.

Comment: I used wireshark to see whether there is some network activity during the instantiation, but it didn't show me something unusual

Comment: This surprises me. The next step would be general profiling using something like AQtime from Automated QA, dotTrace from JetBrains, etc.

Comment: Well, eventually we decided to install SP1, and the problem just disappeared... Unfortunately I don't have any of those profiling tools, so I guess that the problem will remain mysterious.. Thanks for tour help!

Answer (score 1):

Even though it is already outdated, it may be useful for somebody else searching for the same. Problem could be with DNS resolution problem, that might be solved in SP1. So you can check if it happens only when you use host name or also with specified IP address.

Answer (score 0):

Even though this is very old information I just found this issue too although I was experiencing a 7second delay on the First call to a method on the Service Client, I tracked it (in my environment) to Internet Explorer settings as stated above, but in my circumstances it wasn't a Proxy enabled, but the Automatically Detect Settings.

Connections -> Lan Settings and Automatically Detect settings was enabled.

I played with the machine.config and app.config and set

```
<runtime>
  <generatePublisherEvidence enabled="false"/>
</runtime>
```

Which also made no difference.

I found this answer here and thought I'd contribute a little more information in case someone else in the future experiences something like this.

(This with a .Net 4 WCF service)